# Как найти пересекающиеся совпадения, которые соответствуют маске

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Регулярное выражение `/(1|2|3) (?1) (?1)/` находит совпадение `1 1 2` в строке `1 1 2 3 4`. Но в этой строке маске соответствует и кусок `1 2 3`.

Вопрос: мне нужно, чтобы при помощи регулярного выражения находилось и `1 1 2` и `1 2 3`, как это сделать? Используется: pcre, PHP.

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/kO1wD8/2

Comment: `preg_match_all`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Именно `preg_match_all` я и пользуюсь, но он находит только `1 1 2`, `1 2 3` он не находит.

Answer (score 3):

Какой бы ни был шаблон `pattern` регулярного выражения- для поиска всех пересекающихся совпадений достаточно поместить этот шаблон в опережающую проверку:

```
(?=pattern)
```

В таком случае регулярное выражение будет последовательно проверяться для каждой позиции в тексте, а значит способно найти пересекающиеся совпадения:

```
(?=(1|2|3) (?1) (?1))
```

https://regex101.com/r/kO1wD8/3
Такое регулярное выражение находит уже два желаемых вхождения. Такое совпадение имеет нулевую длину, потому что проверяется позиция в тексте, а не текст, а значит для извлечения текста совпадения нужно поместить шаблон в сохраняющую группу `(pattern)`

Хочу сразу предупредить ( https://regex101.com/r/kO1wD8/4 ), что если применить регулярное выражение к тексту:

```
1 1 2 3 4 21 2 1
```

то, возможно, что третье совпадение является нежелательным, чтобы исключить такие совпадения нужно делать ретроспективную проверку на отсутствие цифры перед шаблоном:

```
(?=(?<!\d)(1|2|3) (?1) (?1))
```

https://regex101.com/r/kO1wD8/5

Comment: для последнего случая подойдет `\b`, обозначающий границу слов, и регулярка станет [короче](https://regex101.com/r/kO1wD8/8), избавившись от ретроспективы - `(?=\b(1|2|3) (?1) (?1))`

Comment: Я просто для примера написал, вероятнее всего ТС привел минимально воспроизводимый пример и на самом деле у него в альтернативе не цифры 1, 2, 3, а другие регулярные выражения. По крайней мере мне хочется в это верить :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне в голову приходит только один вариант - сдвигать начало поиска в строке при помощи пятого элемента функции `preg_match_all()`. Возможно существуют более элегантные решения.

```
$str = '1 1 2 3 4';
$pattern = '/(1|2|3) (?1) (?1)/';
for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i += 2) {
  if(preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, $i)) {
    echo $out[0][0].'<br />';
  }
}
```

Результат работы скрипта

```
1 1 2
1 2 3
```