# Наложение вхождений в RegEx Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо найти все позиции вхождений в строке через регулярное выражение.

Пример:

Строка: cgcgcgcgcgcg

Вхождение: cgcg

Использую:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("cgcg");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("cgcgcgcgcgcg");
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
```

Результат:

```
0
4
8
```

А ожидаю получить:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Как учесть все вхождения, включая те, которые будут накладываться?

UPD.
Получилось сделать так, но есть ли более адекватный способ?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("cgcg");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("cgcgcgcgcgcg");
int start = 0;
while (matcher.find(start)) {
    start = matcher.start() + 1;
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно найти все пересекающиеся совпадения с различными начальными позициями в строке. Это можно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения. Для этого вам понадобится позитивный  блок предварительного просмотра вперёд и захватывающая подмаска:

```java
String regex = "cgcg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(" + regex + "))");
// Если regex не шаблон, а простой текст, экранируйте его перед использованием в REGEX
// Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(" + Pattern.quote(regex) + "))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("cgcgcgcgcgcg");
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.start(1));
```

С использованием `streams`:

```java
List<Integer> results = pattern.matcher("cgcgcgcgcgcg")
        .results()
        .map(r -> r.start(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

См. [пример кода в Java](https://ideone.com/FtiGOV)

Результат:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

и

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Если уж совсем всё правильно делать, то `regex` бы ещё заэскейпить :) `Pattern.compile("(?=(" + Pattern.quote(regex) + "))")`.

Comment: Спасибо! а где можно было бы по подробнее почитать про подобные вещи с регулярными выражениями?

Comment: @tasker https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: @tasker На StackOverflow, там много таких примеров. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534331/182013) в общем эту технику описал ReinRaus.